# Cannot see JSF editing tools in RAD 8.5

Tags: jsf, ibm-rad

I installed IBM Rational Application Developer (RAD) 8.5 and I'm trying to create a JSF application, but things are not working as documented. When I create a new Web Project, I do not see "Java Server Faces" template in the list of project templates. The only templates I see are "Dojo Toolkit", "Rest services" and "Simple".
Instead, I created a Dynamic web project, and selected "Java Server Faces v2.0 project" from the list of configuration. The project was indeed created with JSF settings in web.xml and faces-config.xml, but when I create a JSP page, I cannot see the JSF editing tools. There is no JSF palette in the palettes pane. I verified that the Java Server Faces facet is selected in the Project Facets. Anything else I need to do to get the JSF project template and the JSF palette?

Answer (score 1):

I found that JSF tools are not installed by default in RAD 8.5. I modified the installation (using Modify from IBM Installation Manager) and added the JSF tools feature, and now the JSF editing tools are available.